# Pandas average span between dates per category, use the first available

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following data, and I'm looking to find, per animal/category, the average distance between date1 and the first available date2 to answer how much shelter 1 usually receives dogs or cats before shelter 2 (suppose there are hundreds of animal type, not just 2, for simplicity).

That is, for each timestamp in shelter 1, I want to find the nearest timestamp in shelter 2 for that animal.  This may be nan.  There is no guarantee of the same number of events per animal or per shelter.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,1,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,2,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,3,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,4,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,5,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,6,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,7,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,1,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,2,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,5,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,6,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,7,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
])
df1.name ="shelter1"
len(df1)
12

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 1,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 2,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 3,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 4,6), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 5,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 6,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 7,7), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 1,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 3,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 4,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 5,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 6,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 7,4), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
])
df2.name ="shelter2"
len(df2)
13
```

So `shelter2 - shelter1`, `cat` should be about 4 days, and `shelter2 - shelter1`, `dog` has many intervals that are 1 day, but February to March has a full month delay, so it will be larger on average.

What is the operation called to do this date and category date difference, and how can I do it with agg so that I can see mean/median/max etc?

Another way to think of this is I want an asof merge, however, I want the timedelta between t1 and t2, not just pairing them for a join.

What I have tried is the following

```
>>> df1.set_index(["arrival","animal"]) - df2.set_index(["arrival","animal"])
                   value
arrival    animal       
2020-01-01 cat       NaN
2020-01-02 dog       NaN
2020-01-03 dog       NaN
2020-01-05 cat       NaN
2020-02-01 cat       NaN
2020-02-02 dog       NaN
2020-02-05 cat       NaN
2020-03-01 cat       NaN
2020-03-03 dog       NaN
2020-03-05 cat       NaN
2020-04-01 cat       NaN
2020-04-03 dog       NaN
2020-04-06 cat       NaN
2020-05-01 cat       NaN
2020-05-02 dog       NaN
2020-05-03 dog       NaN
2020-05-05 cat       NaN
2020-06-01 cat       NaN
2020-06-02 dog       NaN
2020-06-03 dog       NaN
2020-06-05 cat       NaN
2020-07-01 cat       NaN
2020-07-02 dog       NaN
2020-07-04 dog       NaN
2020-07-07 cat       NaN
```

This is a difference of the values, not of the arrivals.

```
>>> df1.groupby(["arrival","animal"]) - df2.groupby(["arrival","animal"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DataFrameGroupBy' and 'DataFrameGroupBy'
```

I can't subtract the groups it seems.

Another option

```py
>>> df3.groupby(["animal"]).apply(lambda x: x["arrival_x"] - x["arrival_y"])
animal    
cat     0      -4 days
        1     -35 days
        2     -64 days
        3     -96 days
        4    -125 days
                ...   
dog     74    121 days
        75     90 days
        76     60 days
        77     29 days
        78     -2 days
Length: 79, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Is wrong because it is the difference of /all/ timesin shelter 1 - all times in shelter 2, instead of the first available arrival from shelter 2 for each shelter 1 arrival.

You can see the dimensions here are 79 instead of approximately 12 +/- for the paired dates, reducing to 2, one for dog and 1 for cat, for the average values.

Comment: what's your expected output? why do you use `groupby`? is it not just a subtraction that you're after?

Comment: Thanks, @enke.  The thing I'm having a hard time doing is I guess pairing the dates?  For a given date at shelter 1 per animal, choose only the next available date in shelter 2 for the same animal.  Subtract the nearest pair, then for all those timedeltas, what is the average?  It should look basically like the df3 output above, but only 12 tall (one for each df1.arrival and its soonest df2.arrival) rather than 98 tall.

Comment: I don't get it. Something like `df1['difference'] = (df2['arrival'] - df1['arrival']).dt.days` seems to be what you're after but judging from your attempts, maybe not.

Comment: This will only work if they are exactly the same size and there are the same numbers for all animals, right?  The /nearest/ arrival in df2 may obtain for some animals and not for others, and this should be nan.

Comment: ```df1.set_index(["arrival","animal"]) - df2.set_index(["arrival","animal"])``` doesn't work, because indexes are not equal in two dataframes.

Comment: could you include a sample where the dataframes aren't the same shape with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i kinda understand what do you want to achieve, but I am telling you at the start - this method is kinda weird and not optimal.

What you are trying to achieve is:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,1,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,2,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,3,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,4,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,5,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,6,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,7,1), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,1,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,2,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,3,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,4,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,5,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,6,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020,7,2), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
])
df1.name ="shelter1"

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 1,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 2,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 3,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 4,6), "animal": "cat", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 5,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 6,5), "animal": "cat", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 7,7), "animal": "cat", "value": 1},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 1,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 2,4), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 3,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 4,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 2},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 5,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 6,3), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
{"arrival": datetime.date(2020, 7,4), "animal": "dog", "value": 3},
])

df2.name ="shelter2"
#Set cats from df1 and df2
df1cats=df1[df1['animal']=='cat']
df2cats=df2[df2['animal']=='cat']
(df2cats['arrival']-df1cats['arrival']).describe()
```

Same stuff for dogs. However, this method requires EQUAL lengths of both cats and dogs records both in df1 and df2.

Comment: I appreciate your time and the attempt, but I'm looking for a solution, that like an asof merge, will find the nearest/forward match and have nan if not available, rather than one that fails when the lengths are not equals.  I can abridge the sample above to make them not equal explicitly, but I'm also just specifying that in the problem statement.